# Error while trying to send opus encoded audio to a server using gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, opus, python-gstreamer

I am using a [Kaldi-Gstreamer-Server](https://github.com/alumae/kaldi-gstreamer-server) library, which uses python gstreamer bindings, for live speech recognition application. The library uses [onlinegmmdecodefaster](http://kaldi-asr.org/doc/online_programs.html) gstreamer element (which is included with the Kaldi library) along with other elements (decodbin, audioconvert...) to accept audio and transcribe it to text . The library requires when sending a request to the server, the **content-type** query parameter be specified using  GStreamer 1.0 caps format and encoded to the request Url.

When sending raw audio to the server by setting the content-type to `audio/x-raw,format=S16LE,channels=2,layout=interleaved` everything works fine and I get transcription text from the server. However, for low latency, I am trying to encode the audio using opus encoder and send to the server. I set the content-type request parameter to the caps format of the [opusdec](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-plugins/html/gst-plugins-base-plugins-opusdec.html) element pad as this:

```
    audio/x-opus, channel-mapping-family=(int)[ 1, 255 ], channels=(int)[1, 255 ], stream-count=(int)[ 1, 255 ], coupled-count=(int)[ 0, 255 ]
```

However I get the following error while gstreamer tries to use the above capabilities:

> 2017-03-15 13:53:26 - INFO: decoder2:
>   0578f66f-8474-48db-996b-ce401ed5c034: Setting caps to audio/x-opus,
>   channel-mapping-family=(int)[ 1, 255 ], channels=(int)[ 1, 255 ],
>   stream-count=(int)[ 1, 255 ], coupled-count=(int)[ 0, 255 ]
>
> (python:1145): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_event_new_caps: assertion
>   'gst_caps_is_fixed (caps)' failed
>
> (python:1145): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_pad_push_event: assertion
>   'GST_IS_EVENT (event)' failed 2017-03-15 13:53:27 - ERROR: decoder2:
>   (GLib.Error('Internal data flow error.', 'gst-stream-error-quark', 1),
>   'gstbasesrc.c(2933): gst_base_src_loop ():
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAppSrc:appsrc:\nstreaming task paused,
>   reason not-negotiated (-4)') 2017-03-15 13:53:27 - INFO: decoder2:
>   0578f66f-8474-48db-996b-ce401ed5c034: Resetting decoder state
>
> (python:1145): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_event_new_caps: assertion
>   'gst_caps_is_fixed (caps)' failed
>
> (python:1145): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_pad_push_event: assertion
>   'GST_IS_EVENT (event)' failed
>
> (python:1145): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_event_new_caps: assertion
>   'gst_caps_is_fixed (caps)' failed
>
> (python:1145): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_pad_push_event: assertion
>   'GST_IS_EVENT (event)' failed 2017-03-15 13:53:27 - ERROR: decoder2:
>   (GLib.Error('Internal data flow error.', 'gst-stream-error-quark', 1),
>   'gstbasesrc.c(2933): gst_base_src_loop ():
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAppSrc:appsrc:\nstreaming task paused,
>   reason not-negotiated (-4)')

What could be the cause of this error? How can I resolve this so that I can send opus encoded audio data to the server?

Comment: Why opusdec? Encoder is opusenc.

Comment: I also tried with opusenc caps format, but it didn't work.